# Unable to change color of the button

Tags: ios, swiftui

Below is a code I wrote to just change color of a button when pressed. I've been using Flexible grid layout. For some reason, when I click on any of the button, the color does not change. It appears that the StudentRegister class is not being updated. Appreciate any help.

```
struct StudentView: View {
    
    @State var students: [StudentRegister] = [student1, student2]
    
    let layout = [
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible())
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: layout, spacing: 20) {
            ForEach(students, id: \.self) { student in
                VStack() {
                    Button(action: {
                        student.status = Color.green
                    }) {
                        Text(student.name!)
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(student.status!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


class StudentRegister: ObservableObject, Hashable, Equatable {
    var name: String?
    @Published var status: Color?
    
    static func == (lhs: StudentRegister, rhs: StudentRegister) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(name)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct StudentsView: View {
    // Here, we make the `StudentsView` instance subscribe to the
    // `StudentRegister` instance's `objectWillChange` publisher, by wrapping
    // the `studentRegister` instance-property with the `@StateObject` (**not**
    // the `@State`) property wrapper.
    //
    // This, combined with the fact that the `students` instance-property of the
    // `StudentRegister` class has been wrapped with the `@Published` property
    // wrapper, will cause the `StudentsView` instance to be re-rendered
    // whenever we add, remove, or re-order the **references** to `Student`
    // instances that are being stored in the `StudentRegister` instance's
    // `students` Array instance-property.
    @StateObject var studentRegister = StudentRegister()
    
    @State private var isLoading = true
    
    let layout = [
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible())
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if isLoading {
                Text("Loading...")
            } else {
                LazyVGrid(columns: layout, spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach(studentRegister.students, id: \.self) { student in
                        StudentView(student: student)
                            // Changes to the values of properties of the
                            // `Student` instances to which **references** are
                            // being stored in the `StudentRegister` instance's
                            // `students` Array instance-property **won't**
                            // cause the **references** that are being stored in
                            // that Array to change.
                            //
                            // Consequently, changes to the value of the
                            // `status` instance-property of any of the
                            // `Student` instances **won't** cause the
                            // `StudentsView` View to be re-rendered.
                            //
                            // Thus, it would be **unsafe** for us to set the
                            // `foregroundColor` here in this View, given the
                            // fact that its value is dependent on the `status`
                            // property of one of the `Student` instances.
                            // .foregroundColor(student.status) // **Don't** do this.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            // Note: This could obviously be improved with
            // asynchronous-loading in the future.
            studentRegister.load()
            isLoading = false
        }
    }
}

class StudentRegister: ObservableObject {
    @Published var students = [Student]()
    
    func load() {
        students = [.init(name: "Bob Smith", status: .blue), .init(name: "Alice Davidson", status: .yellow)]
    }
}

struct StudentView: View {
    // The use of the `@ObservedObject` property wrapper here, **will** cause
    // the `StudentView` instance to subscribe to the `Student` instance's
    // `objectWillChange` publisher.
    @ObservedObject var student: Student
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            Button(action: {
                student.status = Color.green
            }) {
                Text(student.name)
            }
            // Given that changes to the value of `student.status` will cause
            // **this** `StudentView` instance to be re-rendered, it's safe for
            // us to set the `foregroundColor` (which depends on the value of
            // `student.status`) here in **this** View.
            .foregroundColor(student.status)
        }
    }
}


class Student: ObservableObject, Hashable, Equatable {
    var name: String
    
    @Published var status: Color
    
    init(name: String, status: Color) {
        self.name = name
        self.status = status
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: Student, rhs: Student) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(name)
    }
}

struct StudentsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        StudentsView()
    }
}
```

### Explanation of Solution

#### Storing the instance of the `ObservableObject` in the View that "owns" the instance

You should use `@StateObject` for the property in the highest-level View that holds a particular instance of a class that conforms to the `ObservableObject` protocol. That's because the View containing that property "owns" that instance.

#### Receiving an instance of the `ObservableObject` in lower-level Views

You should use `@ObservedObject` for the properties in lower-level Views to which that instance is **directly** passed, or if you choose to pass the instance down to lower-level View's indirectly by passing it as an argument in a call to the `environmentObject` View Method in the `body` computed property variable of the View that "owns" the instance, you should use `@EnvironmentObject` for the properties in the lower-level Views that need to receive it.

#### What changes cause which ObservableObject's `objectWillChange` Publishers to fire, and which Views will be re-rendered as a consequence.

If you add, remove, or re-order elements in the `studentRegister.students` Array, it will cause the `StudentRegister` instance's `objectWillChange` Publisher to fire, as its `students` property is an `@Published` property, and the adding, removing, or re-ordering of elements in the Array it stores causes the **references/pointers** to `Student` instances that that Array contains to change. This in turn will trigger the `StudentsView` View to be re-rendered, as it's subscribed to that `StudentRegister` instance's `objectWillChange` Publisher due to the fact that it's storing a reference to that instance in an `@StateObject` or `@ObservedObject` or `@EnvironmentObject` property (it's specifically storing it in a `@StateObject` as it happens to "own" the instance).

It's important to note that the `studentRegister.students` Array is storing **references/pointers** to `Student` instances, and hence, changes to properties of any of those `Student` instances **won't** cause the elements of the `studentRegister.students` Array to change. Due to the fact that the changing of one of those `Student` instance's `status` properties **won't** cause the `studentRegister.students` Array to change, it also **won't** cause the `studentRegister` object's `objectWillChange` Publisher to fire, and hence **won't** trigger the `StudentsView` View to be re-rendered.

The changing of one of those `Student` instance's `status` properties **will** cause that `Student` instance's `objectWillChange` Publisher to fire though, due to the fact that the `status` property is an `@Published` property, and thus changes to the property will trigger the `StudentView` View to which the `Student` instance corresponds, to be re-rendered. Remember, like how the `StudentsView` View is subscribed to the `StudentRegister` instance's `objectWillChange` Publisher, the `StudentView` View is subscribed to its `Student` instance's `objectWillChange` Publisher as it's storing a reference to that instance in an `@StateObject` or `@ObservedObject` or `@EnvironmentObject` (it's specifically storing it in an `@ObservedObject`, as it doesn't "own" the `Student` instance, but rather is passed it **directly** by its immediate parent View).